# how to save features in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, postgis

Using openlayers, 
I want to add new features to a vector layer and then save that feature in POSTGIS DB. I want to achieve this functionality using the save button which comes along with openlayers download. Plz provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html) tutorial? It works, but this way you will need a geoserver between openlayers and postgis, I don't know if it is possible without geoserver.

Comment: Yes, I referred to this page previously and tried to code according to it. But, I couldnot do it. And yes, I have Geoserver inbetween Openlayers and Postgis.

Comment: so do you still have problems with it? if yes, could you specify where you got stuck?